# justify the text in beamer with \item

Tags: beamer

I want to justify my text in beamer, however when I've used the  `item`, the text is not justified. Could you help me with that? here is a minimal example. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{epsfig,cite}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ thmtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{commath}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\newcommand{\tabincell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} 
\usetheme{Madrid}}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please post the code in a form that shows the problem (this has no `\documentclass`.  Unrelated but no document written in last 25 years should be using `epsfig` package.

Comment: `\begin{itemize}\justifying` works, but do you really use all those packages in a single presentation? How long is your talk?? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I don't know that I will use all of them or not. I should present for 1 hour.

Comment: ``` \begin{itemize}\justifying``` does not work for me. I don't know why

Comment: Just adding `\justifying` to your file produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqWZu.png) Note it is a really bad idea to add every package on CTAN just in case, it slows down processing and makes weird errors due to package clashes almost inevitable. Start from an empty preamble and only add a package if you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will definitely do that. The ``` \justifiying ``` also works.

Comment: Also, the packages mathtools, mathrsfs, graphicx, booktabs, amssymb are included twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite having written an answer to a question yesterday saying there is no good use for `\justifyng` tracing where beamer has set ragged and making it not do is probably more trouble than it is worth, and you can simply use

```
\begin{itemize}\justifying
```

to reset text justification within the list.